# Changing the CSP of an Ember.js Addon Dummy App

Tags: javascript, ember.js, content-security-policy

I'm working on an ember addon leveraging [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) and `ember-cli` at version `2.18.2` and I'm noticing that PDF.js injects inline styles. The `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` header specifies `style-src 'self';` which results in the logs of `ember serve` exploding with CSP violations being reported to the server via the report only uri with the following message:

```
Content Security Policy violation:

{
  "csp-report": {
    "document-uri": "http://localhost:4200/tests/index.html?testId=46b61910",
    "referrer": "http://localhost:4200/tests/index.html",
    "violated-directive": "style-src",
    "effective-directive": "style-src",
    "original-policy": "default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' localhost:7020 0.0.0.0:7020 undefined:7020; font-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' ws://localhost:7020 ws://0.0.0.0:7020 ws://undefined:7020 http://localhost:4200; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; report-uri http://localhost:4200/csp-report;",
    "disposition": "report",
    "blocked-uri": "inline",
    "line-number": 5270,
    "column-number": 23,
    "source-file": "http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js",
    "status-code": 200,
    "script-sample": ""
  }
}
```

Seeing as the applications we're building that will consume this addon control their own CSP and allows for inline styling, I'd like to disable these warnings but having difficulty tracking down how to do so.

Is it possible to customize the report-only CSP in an Ember.js addon's dummy app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting CSP options is supported via the [ember-cli-content-security-policy](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-content-security-policy) addon.

Providing the following configuration in `tests/dummy/config/environment.js` will prevent the usage of inline styling from having warnings reported by the console and serve logs:

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    ...
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      'style-src': ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
    ...
```